# Meaning of "defined %{"some::string"}" in perl

Tags: perl, refactoring, warnings

i am switching my application from Perl 5.8.8 to Perl 5.16.3 and now i get tons of warnings about the following third party code in SOAP::Lite

```
unless (defined %{"$protocol_class\::Client::" )
```

The code produces the following warings:

```
Warning in Perl code: \t(Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
Warning in Perl code: defined(%hash) is deprecated at /.../SOAP/Lite.pm
line ...
```

If i reduce it to a simple example it looks like

```
unless( defined %{"some::string"} )
```

**Question:** Why should someone interpret a string "some::string" as a hash %{"some::string"} and check if the hash is defined? It doen't make any sense to me. I want to replace this codepiece with something else without breaking the third party module so i can focus on real important warnings and errors.

Here is the whole function. I don't know if this helps because think its some kind of Guru code which is a little bit hard to understand

```
sub proxy {
    my $self = shift;
    $self = $self->new() if not ref $self;

    my $class = ref $self;

    return $self->{_proxy} unless @_;

    $_[0] =~ /^(\w+):/ or die "proxy: transport protocol not specified\n";
    my $protocol = uc "$1"; # untainted now

    # HTTPS is handled by HTTP class
    $protocol =~s/^HTTPS$/HTTP/;

    (my $protocol_class = "${class}::$protocol") =~ s/-/_/g;

    no strict 'refs';
    unless (defined %{"$protocol_class\::Client::"}
        && UNIVERSAL::can("$protocol_class\::Client" => 'new')
    ) {
        eval "require $protocol_class";
        die "Unsupported protocol '$protocol'\n"
            if $@ =~ m!^Can\'t locate SOAP/Transport/!;
        die if $@;
    }

    $protocol_class .= "::Client";
    return $self->{_proxy} = $protocol_class->new(endpoint => shift, @_);
}
```

Comment: Expert level of security there `s/^HTTPS$/HTTP/`. I didn't know it was that simple to add encryption.

Comment: An alternative solution is to just upgrade [`SOAP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) to the latest version.  The modern proxy method doesn't use the deprecated syntax, instead uses: `unless (Class::Inspector->loaded("$protocol_class\::Client") && UNIVERSAL::can("$protocol_class\::Client" => 'new')`

Comment: @Miller: Installing the newest SOAP::Lite was the real solution because there where some other problems (de-/seralizing of perl datastructures) using the old version of SOAP::Lite (0.61) with Perl 5.14. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `%Package::` gives access to a package's *stash*, i.e. the symbol table hash.

All this code is doing is checking whether a given package has been loaded (in which case its stash will exist) and that there is a `new` method for the package. If not then `require` is used to load the module.

The call to `UNIVERSAL::can('package', 'method')` is normally written as `'package'->can('method')` and you can change that here if you like, but the code will work as it stands.

I suggest you do just as the warnings say, and omit the `defined`. It would also be nicer if you put the package name in its own variable instead of using the interpolated double-quoted string twice, and you can use the conventional call to `can` as I have described.  It would look like this

```
my $package = "${protocol_class}::Client";
unless ( %{"${package}::"} and $package->can('new') ) {

  # load missing module
}
```